# php function return variable not working

Tags: php, function

I have created a function(recursive).
It will call again if it has parent id otherwise it will return last Id.
The Problem is I'm unable to return the last Id which passed in the Function argument.
It is showing complete if I use var_dump() or echo but unable to return in return().

Here is Sample Code :

```
function abc($dbcon,$id){
    $get_quy = "select * from member_mst where member_status=0 and pid=".$id;
    $get_rs = $dbcon->query($get_quy);

    $get_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($get_rs);
    $get_rel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_rs);

    if($get_numrows>0){
        abc($dbcon,$get_rel['member_id']);
    }else{
        //var_dump($id);//This will return => "String '3'" 
        return $id;
    }
}
var_dump(abc($dbcon,1));//Returning Null
```

Comment: i think it should be `return abc($dbcon,$get_rel['member_id']);`. You execute the function but never get results from the recursion calls

Comment: And you should fix the SQL injection.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Kaddath It is again calling my function(infinite times).

Comment: @abhichavda What results do you get? Can you add: `print $get_numrows."\n"` before `if($get_numrows>0){`?

Comment: @Kaddath It is worked.
I have used return while calling the function again.
`return abc($dbcon,$get_rel['member_id']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code. The Problem was I wasn't using return() while calling the function again.

```
function abc($dbcon,$id){
    $get_quy = "select * from member_mst where member_status=0 and pid=".$id;
    $get_rs = $dbcon->query($get_quy);

    $get_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($get_rs);
    $get_rel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_rs);

    if($get_numrows>0){
        return abc($dbcon,$get_rel['member_id']); // Updated Code Here
    }else{
        return $id;
    }
}
var_dump(abc($dbcon,1));//Returning "3"
```